# tkinter window and background image don't align properly

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.4

I am writing a Simpsons trivia game as my first big programming project. My question is twofold:

1. Is this the right way to go about creating a background image? Keep in mind that my plan is to include the Simpsons theme song playing in the background as well as one or two buttons on top of the background image.
2. Assuming the code below is the right approach given what I want to accomplish, why am I getting a thin gray line on the left of my image and window? Ie. Why is the image not filling up the window perfectly like it is on the right side?

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.title("The Simpsons Trivia Game")
root.geometry('400x600')
root.resizable(0,0)

def resize_image(event):
new_width = event.width
new_height = event.height
image = copy_of_image.resize((new_width, new_height))
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
label.config(image = photo)
label.image = photo 

image = Image.open('E:\Simpsons Trivia Game\SimpsonsPic.png')
copy_of_image = image.copy()
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
label = ttk.Label(root, image = photo)
label.bind('<Configure>', resize_image)
label.pack(fill=BOTH, expand = YES)

root.mainloop()
```

[tkinter window with background image (left side of window not perfectly alligned with background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHVa7.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand everything, but I managed to get rid of the border (at least on Linux) by doing:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.title("The Simpsons Trivia Game")
root.geometry("400x600")
root.resizable(0,0)

image = Image.open('/tmp/foobar.png')
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
label = ttk.Label(root, image = photo)
label.pack()
label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center")

root.mainloop()
```